# Make a button in main.xml

Tags: android, layout, button, timer

i want simply make this code
i have one button
but when i click that button i want a timer start ..
and every timer tick it make a button in main.xml ..how can i do that? 
please help me sir!

```
  Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
 a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new CountDownTimer(5000,1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //how to create a button here!
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }.start();
    }
});
```

i try this .. but this words appear when i click the button ("Unfortunately program has been stoped")

```
  final int i=1;
    Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new CountDownTimer(5000,1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //how to create a button here!
                LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.main);
                Button btn = new Button(NyaActivity.this);
                btn.setId(i+1);
                linearLayout.addView(btn);
                btn.setText("Button"+(i+1));
                final int index = i;
                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.i("TAG", "The index is" + index);
                    }
                });


            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }.start();
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain the question clearly? what are you trying to ask by "and every timer tick it make a button in main.xml"???

Comment: i mean, in timer tick i want to add a new button ..so if i have new countdowntimer(10000,1000) then i will have 10 button in main.xml ..help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way for adding button dynamically with action on CountDownTimer onTick:

```
    int i=1;
    Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new CountDownTimer(5000,1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //how to create a button here!
                LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlauoutid);
                Button btn = new Button(Your_Current_Activity.this);
                btn.setId(i+1);
                btn.setText("Button"+(i+1));
                btn.setLayoutParams(lprams);
                final int index = i;
                btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.i("TAG", "The index is" + index);
                    }
                });
                linearLayout.addView(btn);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }.start();
    }
});
```

and your layout look like as:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainlauoutid"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
.....
```

Comment: whats wrong? Unfortunately program has been stopped

//this my code for timer tick 
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.main);
                    Button btn = new Button(NyaActivity.this);
                    btn.setId(i+1);
                    linearLayout.addView(btn);
                    btn.setText("Button"+(i+1));

Comment: update your post with latest code and log-cat stack trace.then i will help u

Comment: plz add log cat when your program crashing

Comment: just add `android:id="@+id/mainlauoutid"` in your main.xml layout and in code use `LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlauoutid);` instead of `LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.main)` and see my edit answer

Comment: if still u have problem then download working example https://sites.google.com/site/imrankhanandroid/Buttonclicktest.rar?attredirects=0&d=1 for adding button dynamically  with onclick action

Comment: thanks imran! its works! i have a one question again ..how to set the position of the button? i want the position is random ..please help me

Answer (score 0):

Create LinearLayout in your main.xml and find it before a.setOnClickListener using:

```
final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutId);
```

Then in onTick() call:

```
Button newBtn = new Button(YourActivity.this);
newBtn.setText("new button");
layout.addView(newBtn);
```

Comment: Bundle? What do you mean with it?